# Change Jython standalone jar in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, jython, jython-2.7

I am trying to find a way to replace the version of jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar that is used by Pig on Hadoop. Pig 12 currently uses jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar and I am trying to use jython 2.7 beta4. What is a good way to replace the jython version and make sure that Pig recognizes the change. When I try to replace the jar, Pig still has the old jython jar in path, and I am trying to find the method in which that can be replaced. That version carries all the required libraries. I am using Hadoop v2.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?